# codeigniter and DataMapper. The relationship table in different servers, how?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I hope you can understand me. My English is bad, but not for long.
This error I describe has never happened, the truth is very rare.
In my local machine works perfectly, windows and wamp work :(.
But I uploaded the amazon web with ubuntu linux. And I get the following error.

```
Error Number: 1146
Table 'admin.paginas_servicios' does not exist
```

It really does not exist, the table that there is 'admin.servicios_paginas', but the funny thing is that on my local machine works.

So now as I get the following error now change the name of the table admin.paginas_servicios, ok?.
 But in my local machine does not work and I get the following error, otherwise:

```
Error Number: 1146
Tabla 'admin.servicios_paginas' no existe
```

Because this happens with relationship tables and models.

may be for the operating system?

by calling the tables with names in Spanish?

I do not understand :(

I hope you can help me.
A greeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably is a problem with inflector_helper. I would recommend you to explicitly set $table and $name in your model class. Maybe it's an error in the relations ($has_one and $has_many properties). Another tip to keep in count is that you must name relationships using model names alphabetically ordered.

Please provide more code.

PS: I'm Spanish, so send me a PM in order to try to help you and then we'll update this entry to register the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the end the problem was for the windows operating system. I'm migrating to ubuntu :)

The problem was for two reasons:

1 - Because the models it had the first word written with uppercase. When should be in lowercase. In windows ignores, but not linux.

2 - when creating tables for relationship with DataMapper no problem with the order to name them.
example:

If your relationship name is "page_image" would not have problems in windows, but the reality is that DataMapper handles relations alphabetically, so it has to be "image_page".

So work on windows and linux perfectly.

Thanks!